# Reading from text file into array but no such element exception occuring?

Tags: arrays, file, exception, text, integer

I'm a beginner in Computer Science and I am having a bit of trouble trying to put integers from a text file into an array.  There are seven lines of integers in the text file and each line has 3 integers separated by a space such as :

```
0 15 20
100 25 96
85 42 15
52 63 47
85 44 98 
41 55 74
85 74 15
```

I am supposed to place the three numbers in each line into three different arrays so that one array will contain the first number, the second array will contain the second number, and the third array will contain the third number, all from the same line.
My code is below but when it run it, I obtain a no such element exception and when I print the first array, it shows the first number stored in the first position of the array but then the rest of the numbers are the second numbers of each line. What is going on in the loop?:( I would appreciate any type of explanation.

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    public class Trying{
    public static void main(String [] args){
    Scanner s=null;
    int [] a= new int [7];
    int [] b= new int [7];
    int [] c= new int [7];
    int i=0;
    try{
      s= new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
      while(s.hasNextLine()){
        String line=s.nextLine();
        Scanner cal= new Scanner(line);
        a[i]=cal.nextInt();
        b[i]=cal.nextInt();
        c[i]=cal.nextInt();
        i++; 
      }
    }
    catch(Exception eee){
      eee.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace "c[i]=s.nextInt();" with "c[i]=**cal**.nextInt();". I think you mistakenly used the s scanner object instead of the cal scanner object.

You can also use String.split() method for your purposes. 
Instead of using

```
String line=s.nextLine();
    Scanner cal= new Scanner(line);
    a[i]=cal.nextInt();
    b[i]=cal.nextInt();
    c[i]=s.nextInt();
```

You might try this:

```
String[] lines=s.nextLine().split(" ");
    a[i]=Integer.parseInt(lines[0]);
    b[i]=Integer.parseInt(lines[1]);
    c[i]=Integer.parseInt(lines[2]);
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually didn't notice I was calling the s scanner instead of the cal scanner but that was a little mistake typing it out here :) I'll try what you said , so whenever I scan a line, I have to split it up to get rid of the spaces? I am sorry for this question , as I said , I'm barely beginning in this and have no one else to ask.